# "An error occurred while creating the pipeline. " VS code error

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

This error is displayed in the terminal section when I want to run any code in any language in Visual Studio.

```
One or more errors occurred.
One or more errors occurred.
Cannot load PSReadline module.  Console is running without PSReadline.
```

then it shows this: unable to resolve ${workspacefolder} in configuration ("workspaceFolder")

and this error is displayed when I open Windows PowerShell and does not accept any commands and says:

```
An error occurred while creating the pipeline.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you check the [existing StackOverflow q&a's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PowerShell+Cannot+load+PSReadline+module&tab=votes) for this issue?

Comment: I did but it didn't work. whatever I type it says "an error occurred while creating the pipeline"